# how to replace the date across multiple word documents using powershell

Tags: powershell, scripting

**Objective:** to find all word document files in a specific folder and then find the date within these doc files and change the date before converting all of the files to pdf files.

(Background:- I have like 100 files with dates inside of the files that all need to be uniform. I then need to change all of the files to pdf).

Here's what i have so far:

```
$scriptHome= Split-Path -parent $Myinvocation.Mycommand.Definition
$word_app = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
# This filter will find .doc as well .docx documents
Get-ChildItem -Path $documents_path -Filter *.doc? | ForEach-Object {
$document = $word_app.Documents.Open($_.FullName)
$pdf_filename = "$($_.DirectoryName)\$($_.BaseName).pdf"
$document.SaveAs([ref] $pdf_filename, [ref] 17)
$document.Close()
}
$word_app.Quit()
```

Comment: Why are you using `[ref]`?

Comment: to clarify - after you open the document ($document = ....)  you want to add logic to change some text inside the file and then save as pdf

Comment: Not sure if you've seen this yet but technet has a decent set of documentation with examples in c# of how to do this. the process isn't TOO different in PowerShell - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa192495(v=office.11).aspx#wordobject_link10